# Refresh star color from ratingbar in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors, ratingbar

I have a problem when i try to change my stars color from RatingBar into a ListView Adapter and i don´t understand why is not working because outside the listview everything seems to work properly with same code.

My code for changing star color is:

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(holder.ratingBar.getProgressDrawable(), pContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
```

Anyone encounter this problem?

**Update**: I fixed my problem with this code

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) holder.ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(0)), Color.RED);   // Empty star
        DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(1)), Color.BLUE); // Partial star
        DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(2)), Color.BLUE);  // Full star
```

Comment: Please post your adapter code

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are encounter a similar problem as this, seems to be a bug in the support library.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172067